# Verb conjugations such as 思わん、言えん

Tags: verbs, contractions

I have seen these forms used in manga:

> 1) いや一概にあほとは言えん
>
> 2) そう思わんですか！
>
> 3) 入らん人々は...

Are these simply the negative forms, or are they something else?

Comment: ん is contracted from ぬ which acts as a negation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are simply contracted forms of the negations of those verbs, i. e.
`思わん＝思わぬ／思わない` etc.