# Questions about dialogue in this picture (omitted を、一歩も歩けん)

Tags: meaning, negation, contractions

The dialogue in this picture is simple enough for me up until 一歩も歩けん. The first half makes me expect the whole sentence to be 一歩も引かない but the sentence as a whole confuses me.

[image]

What is this 歩けん especially? Why does it end in ん? Google didn't offer much help either. Also, 血よこせ should be 血をよこせ right? But I get the feeling the を was omitted intentionally. Is omitting を in such obvious and informal cases(it's obvious they're demanding blood so the sentence is understandable) a form of acceptable grammar or is it simply wrong(on purpose or not)?

Comment: @naruto Maybe this [Is verb ending ない shortened to ん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16226/)? Sorry! My bad! I simply searched for "ん negation" and copied & pasted Chocolate's duplicate suggestions under the first post that came up without reading their content carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

歩けん is a variant of 歩けない ("I can't walk"). Usually a small girl doesn't use this form because it sounds a little old-fashioned or dialectal. Maybe the speaker is an old vampire or someone playing the role of it?

- [Is verb ending ない shortened to ん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16226/5010)
- [Verb conjugations such as 思わん、言えん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44432/5010)

The omission of を is very common in colloquial Japanese. There is nothing special.

Comment: That's definitely it. The character is a vampire so that supports your answer even more.